# How to enable cors in django (DJANDO + REACT)

Tags: reactjs, django, cors, django-cors-headers

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/lessons/student' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

xhr.js:177 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/lessons/student net::ERR_FAILED
```

On my localhost it works good, I get data from API but when my friend tries to go to the "Lessons" page and fetch data it shows that error;

In the backend, I downloaded django-cors or whatever it is called and did everything as said

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',

    'News',
    'Users',
    'Lessons',
    'Tests',
    'GradeBook',
    'Schedule',
    'DeadLines'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
```

]

I fetch data using redux-thunk with axios

```
 const lesson = await axios.get(`${url}/lessons/student`, {
        headers: {
          "Authorization": "JWT " + getState().auth.token.access,
        }
      })
```

I have checked a lot of answers to similar problem but they only say that I should install django-cors..enable cors...lalal... I do everything reload the server even localhost but it still doesn't work.

It also isn't a problem with the browser, my friend tried chrome since he used opera.
One more time, on my computer it works nice. I get the data once I visit the webpage, if I try it on another computer it shows and error. How can I solve this questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the `corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware` before all the middlewares (i.e) `MIDDLEWARE = ['corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', ...]`.

Refer: https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/